# How to maintain session using selenium with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, session, session-cookies

I’m trying to get product price which appears only after logging in, but it doesn't work as I expected.

・Logging in its self works after *# login button click,*

・it seems like ***driver2*** can't get take over session information.

How can I pass on session information from driver1 to driver2?

Python 3.10.12

Google Collab

*code*

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install beautifulsoup4

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
from time import sleep
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


USER = "USER"
PASS = "PASS"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

driver1.get("https://www.shozaioh.com/mypage/login")
time.sleep(3)

# login
element = driver1.find_element(By.ID,'login_email')
element.clear()
element.send_keys(USER)

element = driver1.find_element(By.ID,'login_pass')
element.clear()
element.send_keys(PASS)

# login botton click
login_button = driver1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn.btn-info.btn-block.btn-lg")
time.sleep(3)
login_button.click()



# 2. setting session information
session_cookies = driver1.get_cookies()
session_id = None

for cookie in session_cookies:
    if cookie["name"] == "session_id": 
        session_id = cookie["value"]
        break

# 3. new webdriver
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

driver2.get("https://www.shozaioh.com/product_903800.html")  # access product detail page

# 4. new driver session
if session_id:
    driver2.add_cookie({"name": "session_id", "value": session_id})  # セッションIDを設定



# Get product price
product_price = driver2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td#detail_description_box__class_range_sale_price strong.price")
#product_price = driver2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.login > a[href*='/mypage/login']")


if product_price:
    price_text = product_price.text.strip()
else:
    print("you cant find product price")

# quit WebDriver
driver1.quit()
driver2.quit()
```

I tried to use pickle to solve this problem, but it doesn't work.

I want extract "64,728" as below

HTML which appears after logging in:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">参考売価</th>
    <td rowspan="2">\ 80,910（税込 \ 89,000）</td>
    <th>卸価格</th>
    <td id="detail_description_box__class_range_sale_price"> <strong class="price">\ 64,728</strong>（税込 \ 71,200） <span class="per">80%</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>店舗様利益額</th>
    <td> 1個販売あたり<strong>\ 16,182<small>以上の利益</small></strong> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```